# Print line n-1 (and n) if line n fulfills condition

Tags: awk

I have a fasta file looking something like this:

```
>19 dna:chromosome chromosome:NCBIM37:19:1:61342430:1 37330562 ID13406 U -
TACATGGGTGACAAGGAGGTCAGGTGTTA
>19 dna:chromosome chromosome:NCBIM37:19:1:61342430:1 37330584 ID57999 U -
TGTCAAAGGAAGCCTTACTATACATGG
```

The lines beginning with ">" are headers, the others data.

I want to remove all non-header lines that are shorter than 26 or longer than 31. I also want to remove the header belonging to those lines (i.e. the previous line.)

My code so far

```
awk '
{if (substr($0,1,1) == ">") 
    {header=$0} 
else 
    {if ((length($0) > 25) && (length($0) < 32)) {print $header "\n" $0}}}' *
```

but this gives me the error message

```
awk '{if (substr($0,1,1) == ">") {header=$0} else {if ((length($0) > 25) && (length($0) < 32)) {print $header $0}}}' *
), name "header"ld $(>19 dna:chromosome chromosome:NCBIM37:19:1:61342430:1 37330562 ID13406 U -
 input record number 2, file Cluster_1.fas
 source line number 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you said:

```
print $header
```

..instead of:

```
print header
```

You want an un-interpolated variable content.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like it's easier to solve it with `sed`:

```
sed '/^>/{N;/\n.\{26,31\}$/!d}'
```

small explanation:

`/^>/` matches to a string with header 
`{}` applies command group to a pattern 
`N` appens next line to a pattern 
`/\n.\{26,31\}$/` checks if symbols count is between 26 .. 31 
`!d` if matched just pass it, otherwise delete